# How to use variables in JavaScript in Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have created an exec command in Grunt:

exec: {
            iis_command: {
                command: 'c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set vdir \"Default Web Site/\" -physicalPath:[pwd]',
                stdout: false,
                stderr: false
                         },
          },
});

I have put two variables at the top of my Grunt file:

```
var path = require('path');.
var pwd = path.resolve();
```

when I run the iis command this does not work as the variables seem to be used incorrectly. Please can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I actually used the built in global variable in Node.js __dirname

```
exec: {
  iis_command: {
    command: 'c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set vdir \"Default Web Site/\" -physicalPath:' + __dirname,
    stdout: false,
    stderr: false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables in javascript strings do not get interpreted automatically, you need to concatenate them:

```
exec: {
  iis_command: {
    command: 'c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set vdir \"Default Web Site/\" -physicalPath:' + pwd,
    stdout: false,
    stderr: false
  },
}
```